# Error: There can be only one type named "Upload" - Apollo, Express, Type-Graphql

Tags: typescript, express, apollo-server, typegraphql

I am trying to run a simple Mutation in order to Upload an Image, but I am stack with this error:
"Error: There can be only one type named "Upload"."

this is my code

```
import { FileUploadI, GraphQLUpload } from 'graphql-upload'

@Mutation(() => Picture)
  async uploadPicture(@Arg('data', () => GraphQLUpload) data: FileUploadI): Promise<Picture> {
    //.. implementation
  }
```

I am using Apollo and Express as Server and Typescript with Type-Graphql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this Error is Apollo 2.0 "File Upload" feature.

You can read more about this feature in follow link:

https://www.apollographql.com/blog/file-uploads-with-apollo-server-2-0-5db2f3f60675

the package 'graphql-upload' has scalar type Upload and Apollo server use 'graphql-upload' to handle file uploads too.

Maybe you can solve this problem using the apollo "file upload" feature, or, renaming the Upload that came from 'graphql-upload'.